# What does the fragment write to the monitor?

Tags: java, arrays

i am having some difficulty understanding arrays. in the following set of code? What does the fragment write to the monitor? I would really appreciate a detailed answer. Kind regards.

```
public class array {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 int[] array = { 1, 4, 3, 6, 8, 2, 5};
                  int what = array[0];

                  // scan the array
                  for ( int index=0; index < array.length; index++ )
                  { 
                    if ( array[ index ] < what )   
                      what = array[ index ];  
                  }
                  System.out.println( what ); 

      }

}
```

Comment: It prints out the integer 1. It creates an array of 7 integers, grabs the value at the first index which is 0, and saves it into the "what" variable. Then it loops through that same array checking if any of the other values in the array are less than the variable "what". If it is ever true it replaces what with the lower value. Lastly it prints out the value of "what".

Answer (score 2):

This loop will find the smallest element in the array.

Lets go through it step by step.

```
int[] array...
```

This creates an array of intereger values. It doesnt have a fixed size in the [] brackets (which normally is required) because an **initializer list** is provided.

I am talking about this:

```
int array = {1,4,3,6,8,2,5} // the part in the brackets
```

This initializes all values in the array and in this case makes sure the array is exactly the size required by the values (in this case it needs 7 values in the array)

```
int what = array[0];
```

This variable is badly named. I would call it "min" or "smallestVal". Its set to the first element in the array.

```
for ( int index=0; index < array.length; index++ )
```

this is a simple for loop. The first part (first part ends after the first ';') creates a new variable, which is only available in the for loop, that is set to 0. The 2nd part (ends after 2nd ';') is supposed to determine when the loop will end (in this case when the index variable has grown bigger or equal to the length of the array AKA when the loop has reached and processed the last element).
The 3rd part (ends after 3rd ';') is what happens each time the code in the curly brackets is repeated (in this case the index is increased by 1)

```
if( array[index] < what)
```

This checks if the value that is currently being processed (aka the value in the array at position index) is smaller or equal to 'what'.

If thats true then

```
what = array[index];
```

What is made to the new smaller value

This entire loop is supposed to find the **smallest** value in the array.

therefore what is '1' and thats also what is printed to the console.

Hope I could help